# Where are the datasets such as `iris` and `baseball` for use with the Pandas tutorials

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Going through the pandas docs there are some points where they import data from csv files, but it's not clear where one should get these files from.

Searching the site for `read_csv` one can see that there's use of the `iris` dataset as well as the `baseball` dataset, but where to get these datasets for use with the tutorials on the Pandas site is unclear.

So my question is, if one wants to follow through the tutorials on the Python Pandas site where should the datasets be obtained from in order to do so.

Comment: @jezrael thanks - this isn't outlined on the pandas documentation so i think it's a reasonable question. For example - if one uses the seaborn iris set the formatting is different to that of the set used in the pandas documentation

Comment: @jezrael that's unfortunate - I disagree that this is a duplicate of where to find data though as it's specifically about the data used in the pandas tutorial, the other user has answered with the sklearn link and this doesn't really answer the question, in my opinion. Neither does the link with seaborn etc. Not having the data accessible for the tutorials is a bit unfortunate though.

Comment: @baxx Can you give a link to the documentation you mentioned?

Comment: @baxx I deleted my answer. Hope you find what you're searching for :)

Comment: @ayhan if you search the pandas documentation for `read_csv` there are some examples, [here's a link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/search.html?q=read_csv&check_keywords=yes&area=default#). Searching [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=read_csv) for baseball will bring up a use of `read_csv('data/baseball.csv')`

Comment: I believe they are taken from the data folder under the doc folder: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/master/doc/data

Comment: @ayhan - good catch. Maybe question is why not used more in pandas docs? Samples are official?

Comment: @ayhan - Maybe best ask offical, from my experience I never seen to use this samples, only from seaborn :) Maybe only some people use it

Comment: @jezrael yea - and the formatting in the seaborn is a bit different (column names). Seems that these should be linked in the docs... but I've included an outline of an answer in my post, if anyone takes that / polishes it as needed I'll accept.

Comment: @ayhan - check and create answer - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57944166/where-are-the-datasets-such-as-iris-and-baseball-for-use-with-the-pandas-tut?noredirect=1#comment102302614_57944166)

Answer (score 0):

Datasets for the Pandas documentation / tutorial can be found here :

- https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/tree/master/doc/data

One can either download these and import locally, or using pandas `read_csv` they could 
be opened using the raw content.

For the baseball data:

- open the above url
- click on the baseball file
- select `"raw"` from the top right above the file
- copy the url and use as follows

```py
import pandas as pd
raw_baseball_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/doc/data/baseball.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(raw_baseball_url)
```